# Unable to dynamically calculate an input value onchange

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get this calculator to work in my WordPress blog but haven't been successful at it.

I did get simple Hello world pop-up to work but not this. I want to calculate the "BPodds". Can you guys tell me what's wrong with this?

```js
function calcStake() {
    var BWodds = document.getElementById('BWodds').value;
    var div = document.getElementById('div').value;
    var BPodds = ((BWodds - 1) / div) + 1;
    document.getElementById('BPodds').innerHTML = BPodds;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="0" width="500" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">

  <tbody>
    <tr class="calcheading">
      <td colspan="3"><strong>Each Way Lay Calculator</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calchead">
      <td align="center">Bookmaker Win odds:</td>
      <td align="center">Place divider:</td>
      <td align="center">Bookmaker Place odds:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
      <td align="center">
        <input id="BWodds" type="text" value="10" onchange="calcStake()" />
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input id="div" type="text" value="4" onchange="calcStake()" />
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input id="BPodds" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `value` instead of `innerHtml`:

```
 document.getElementById('BPodds').value = BPodds;
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o5ze12mf/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Wordpress,
You are trying to put the result in INPUT with innerHTML but to change the value of INPUT you need to use .value
You code will be like this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function calcStake() {
    var BWodds = document.getElementById('BWodds').value;
    var div = document.getElementById('div').value;
    var BPodds = ((BWodds - 1) / div) + 1;
    document.getElementById('BPodds').value = BPodds;
}
</script>
<table class="table" border="0" width="500" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="calcheading">
            <td colspan="3"><strong>Each Way Lay Calculator</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calchead">
            <td align="center">Bookmaker Win odds:</td>
            <td align="center">Place divider:</td>
            <td align="center">Bookmaker Place odds:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow">
            <td align="center">
                <input id="BWodds" type="text" value="10" onchange="calcStake()" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input id="div" type="text" value="4" onchange="calcStake()" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input id="BPodds" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I just changed

```
document.getElementById('BPodds').innerHTML = BPodds;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('BPodds').value = BPodds;
```